# Delete all but one marker in Android Google Maps V2

Tags: android

So I have some places of interests shown to user via markers with respect to their current location (which is also shown as a blue marker on the map).

What I want, is to sustain the location marker on the map, remove all the other markers, and refresh it after certain conditions are met. I was able to do all that except the sustaining user location marker + overlay circle.

I know that there's `map.clear();` function but wouldn't it also clear the current location marker? How to achieve what I want to?

Thanks.

Comment: an individual marker itself has a method called remove(). do a recursive loop to remove the marker you want

Comment: How/where do I store references to multiple markers I am adding on the map and how do I remove them all?

Comment: I use an array to store reference to those markers. There maybe another better practice, but you got the idea. Each time i want to delete a marker, just call myMarkerArray.remove(0).remove();